# Syncing Messages in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, messages

I have two iPhones - 12 and CE from 2022. They both have the iOS 16.5 and are signed up with one (same on both devices) Apple ID.

The two devices are in different locations. Message backup has been turned on to iClound for both devices.

- no iCloud email
- iCloud backs up both devices

The Apple ID is added in under Settings > Messages > Send/Receive messages.

But the messages do not sync on the iPhone 12. The user uses CD and has a SIM card in it. 12 does not have a SIM card.  Just works on WIFI. Can send message to another user from 12 and it shows up correctly to that  user.

I expected that the messages would sync to both devices, and would like some process to fix / enable that.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

##### Enable iCloud syncing on both of your iPhones.

For this, go to Settings > [your name] > iCloud. And turn on for Messages.

Make sure this setting is enabled on both your iPhones.
Since you have the same Apple ID on both of your iPhones, it should sync properly.

Comment: 16.5 is available and is the latest build - if the OP wants to edit what they actually are running, that's cool. Also, since the OP says message backup / sync is enabled - this might need to be changed to be relevant if they already did what you're proposing.

Comment: @bmike Oh sorry, didn't know that, I thought it was only the beta which was available. I suggest we delete those comments since they have nothing to do with the answer, after you.